# Changing font-awesome class not working correctly on IE11

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

I'm having a cross-browser issue here. Please see the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/utcxvxk0/1/

This short script is simply rendering four loader icons using fa-spinner and fa-pulse.
Then on the document load I change the classes to fa-check.

Here is the HTML:

```
<i id="i1" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
<i id="i2" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
<i id="i3" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
<i id="i4" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
```

And this is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#i4').attr('class', 'fa fa-check');
  $('#i3').attr('class', 'fa fa-check');
  $('#i1').attr('class', 'fa fa-check');
  $('#i2').attr('class', 'fa fa-check');
});
```

This is all working fine in Firefox and Chrome.
However, in IE11, only the first element is displayed correctly and the second throught the fourth are changed into a checkmark, but they keep spinning.

It looks like for some reason, the animation is not being stopped on IE.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

EDIT: simplified version

Comment: Instead of replacing the `attr()`, try using `toggleClass()`: `toggleClass('fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-check');`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it. No dice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I've found a workaround by wrapping the icon in a div and replacing the entire element with the new one with updated classes.
If anyone comes up with a real solution I'll still accept that as answer.

New HTML:

```
<div id="c1"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></div>
<div id="c2"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></div>
<div id="c3"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></div>
<div id="c4"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></div>
```

New js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#c4').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
  $('#c3').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
  $('#c1').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
  $('#c2').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
});
```

New fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/utcxvxk0/3/

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle works fine on my IE version 11.

I would try:

- Make sure any compatibility settings aren't turned on
- Push updates on IE
- Reset IE - click the settings gear in the top corner and select
  Internet Options. Click the Advanced tab and click Reset. This will clear all your cache and temp files

Comment: Tried this but the problem persists. My IE version is 11.0.9600.18205. New versions are installed automatically.